# Polymer Paper Tabs Scrollable problems

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.0, when I try to add the scrollable option for the tabs, the width seems to become 0.

```
<paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
    <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <span class="flex"></span>

    <!-- Toolbar icons -->
    <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>

    <!-- Application name -->
    <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name">Polymer Starter Kit</div>

    <!-- Tabs -->
    <paper-tabs id="scrollableTabs" tabindex="0" selected="0" scrollable class="bottom x-scope self-end paper-tabs-0">
        <paper-tab>Bordeaux</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Burgundy</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Champagne</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Rhone</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>France</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Italy</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Spain</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Americas</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Australia & NZ</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Rest of World</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>Spirits & Fortifieds</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

</paper-toolbar>
```

If I remove the scrollable, they appear normally.

The doc says `If true, tabs are scrollable and the tab width is based on the label width.` That's great... But where to set that label width?

Comment: In the Demo it specifies a width in tabs eg --- <paper-tabs selected="0" class="bottom self-end" style="width: 300px;">  -- try to see if it helps

Comment: Damn.... was so simple! I spent a long time trying to put a width to the elements, but didn't think about paper-tabs itself. If you create a reply I can accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: no problem. for future ref if you right click on the demo and choose view frame source, it will display the demos  source code

Comment: @Tasos Yes, this I did, but the demo didn't have any width assigned, and like I said in my answer below, it's because of setting it to bottom that the width vanishes. There is no examples doing what I needed to do. Anyway thanks for your help that put me on the good path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the hint of @Tasos in the comment, I managed to make it work simply with a `flex` on the paper-tabs, and did some tests.
In the Scrollable demo, it works fine without width only because it's does not have the class `bottom` in the toolbar, that is what messes up the width.